# No carga la imagen en un UpdateView con 2 formularios Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

Cuando realizo el submit todos los campos se actualizan excepto el de la foto de perfil, no genera ningún error, simplemente no carga la imagen

El request.POST me regresa lo siguiente en un print que coloque en el metodo post

```
<tr><th><label for="id_foto_perfil">Foto de perfil:</label></th><td><input type="file" name="foto_perfil" accept="image/*" id="id_foto_perfil"></td></tr>
```

Nota: por el admin de Django puedo cargar la imagen sin problemas

El modelo donde cargo la imagen es este

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    foto_perfil = models.ImageField(upload_to='usuarios/perfil', null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='foto de perfil')
    #otros campos
```

Esta es la vista que estoy usando

```
class PerfilUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Empleado
    model_user = User
    form_class = PerfilForm
    form_class_user = PerfilUsuarioForm
    template_name = 'talento_humano/perfil.html'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return Empleado.objects.get(usuario=self.request.user)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PerfilUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        empleado = self.get_object()
        usuario = self.model_user.objects.get(id=empleado.usuario_id)
        if 'form' not in context:
            context['form'] = self.form_class()
        if 'form_user' not in context:
            context['form_user'] = self.form_class_user(instance=usuario)
        context['id'] = empleado.pk
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object
        empleado = self.get_object()
        usuario = self.model_user.objects.get(id=empleado.usuario_id)
        form = self.form_class(request.POST, instance=empleado)
        form_user = self.form_class_user(request.POST, instance=usuario)
        print(form_user)
        if form.is_valid() and form_user.is_valid():
            # empleado = form.save(commit=False)
            # empleado.usuario = form_user.save()
            form_user.save()
            empleado.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
        else:
            return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form, form_user=form_user))

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('perfil') + '?ok'
```

Y estos son los formularios

```
class PerfilForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Empleado
        fields = ['titulo_obtenido', 'carrera_profesional']


class PerfilUsuarioForm(UserChangeForm):
    password = None

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('foto_perfil', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'celular', 'email')
```

Y este el form del template

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
    {‌{ form_user|crispy }}
    {‌{ form|crispy }}
    <br>
    <button type="submit" value="Actualizar" class="btn btn-primary">
        <i class="ace-icon fa fa-check bigger-120"></i>Actualizar
    </button>
    <a href="{% url 'mi_agenda.listar' %}" class="btn btn-default">Ir a Mi Agenda</a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que además del request.POST, te faltaría añadirle request.FILES en el formulario.m lo cual cambiaría de:

```
form = self.form_class(request.POST, instance=empleado)
```

a

```
form = self.form_class(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=empleado)
```

Una vez lo utilicé así, la info la saqué de acá: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/01/how-to-upload-files-with-django.html

Ah, otra cosa, creo que tambien debes agregar el form.save() antes o después del form_user.save()

Saludos cordiales

Comment: Efectivamente, me falto indicar request.FILES en el form de usuario. Muchas gracias.